# Finding the independent term of an expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

The question and the answer are provided below; however, I have no idea what strategy was implemented to achieve that answer. I would like to know what is happening to solve this question and what each of the lines serves to do. In other words, Just walk me through it, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they used (twice) is $$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$$
Here $a$ and $b$ are some simple powers of $x$ multiplied by some numbers. In the first expression $a=1\cdot x^{-2}$ and $b=(-3)\cdot x^1$. Then they did the same thing for the second term, with $c=(1/2)x^{-1}$ and $d=1\cdot x^2$.
You can now figure out the powers of $x$ in the expanded from of each term. So for the first expression, in the order that I wrote the first equation, the powers of $x$ are $-2\cdot3,-2\cdot2+1,-2+1\cdot2, 1\cdot3$ or $-6, -3, 0, 3$. You can do the same for the second expression. When you multiply, you make all possible combinations with one power from the first expression, added with a power in the second one. Choose only the terms where the sum is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\bracks{x^{0}}
\pars{{1 \over x^{2}} - 3x}^{3}
\pars{{1 \over 2x} + x^{2}}^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{x^{0}}
{1 \over x^{6}}\pars{1 - 3x^{3}}^{3}
{1 \over 8x^{3}}\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\bracks{x^{9}}\pars{1 - 3x^{3}}^{3}
\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\bracks{x^{9}}
\pars{1 - 9x^{3} + 27x^{6} - 27x^{9}}
\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\
\overbrace{\bracks{x^{9}}\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}}
^{\ds{2^{3}{3 \choose 3}}}\ -\
{9 \over 8}\
\overbrace{\bracks{x^{6}}\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}}
^{\ds{2^{2}{3 \choose 2}}}
\\[2mm] - &\
{27 \over 8}
\underbrace{\bracks{x^{3}}\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}}
_{\ds{2^{1}{3 \choose 1}}}\ -\
{27 \over 8}\
\underbrace{\bracks{x^{0}}\pars{1 + 2x^{3}}^{3}}
_{\ds{2^{0}{3 \choose 0}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
1 - {27 \over 2} + {81 \over 4} -{27 \over 8} =
\bbx{35 \over 8} \\ &
\end{align}